# Issue in encode/decode in python 3 with non-ascii character

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to use python3 unicode_escape to escape \n in my string, but the challenge is there are non-ascii characters present in the whole string, and if I use utf8 to encode and then decode the bytes using unicode_escape then the special character gets garbled. Is there any way to have the \n escaped with a new line without garbling the special character?

```
s = "hello\\nworld└--"
print(s.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape'))

Expected Result:
hello
world└--

Actual Result:
hello
worldâ--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user wowcha observes, the `unicode-escape` codec assumes a `latin-1` encoding, but your string contains a character that is not encodable as `latin-1`.

```
>>> s = "hello\\nworld└--"
>>> s.encode('latin-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2514' in position 12: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Encoding the string as `utf-8` gets around the encoding problem, but results in [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) when decoding from `unicode-escape`

The solution is to use the [backslashreplace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) error handler when encoding.  This will convert the problem character to an escape sequence that can be encoded as `latin-1` and does not get mangled when decoded from `unicode-escape`.

```
>>> s.encode('latin-1', errors='backslashreplace')
b'hello\\nworld\\u2514--'

>>> s.encode('latin-1', errors='backslashreplace').decode('unicode-escape')
'hello\nworld└--'

>>> print(s.encode('latin-1', errors='backslashreplace').decode('unicode-escape'))
hello
world└--
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are having is that `unicode_escape` was deprecated in Python 3.3 and it seems to be assuming your code is 'latin-1' due to that being the original codec used within the `unicode_excape` function...

Looking at [the python documentation for codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) we see that `Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode literal in ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are not escaped. Decodes from Latin-1 source code. Beware that Python source code actually uses UTF-8 by default.` which tells us that `unicode_escape` assumes that your text is ISO Latin-1.
So if we run your code with latin1 encoding we get this error:

```
s.encode('latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2514' in position 12: ordinal not in range(256)
```

And the unicode character error is `'\u2514'` which when converted is `'└'` the simplest way to put it is the character cannot be used within a Latin-1 string hence why you get a different character.

I also think it's right to point out that within your string you have `'\\n'` and not just `'\n'` the extra backslash means this symbol is not carriage return but instead it is ignored the backward slash indicates to ignore the `'\n'`. Perhaps try not using the `\\n`...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second escape backslash and decode using utf8:

```
>>> s = "hello\nworld└--"
>>> print(s.encode('utf8').decode('utf8'))
hello
world└--
```